# What's the difference between the two controller definitions?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

When I run the code, Option `A` is failed but not sure what the reason is.

```
angular.module('app').controller('controllerA', function($scope, $http) {
      // code
}

angular.module('app').controller('controllerB', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
     // code
}]);
```

I tried to test it on Angular 1.x JSFiddle, but both of them work well.
Help me!

Comment: if you would minify your .js file, first case will have `function(a,b){...}` and lose pre-defined variables `$scope` and `$http` in the injection. Whereas the second one will be minified, but keep the information about which variable does what, i.e. `'$scope'` -> `a`, `'$http'` -> `b`. Your first case will also do the same thing if you add: `controllerA.$inject = ["$scope", "$http"];`

Comment: With [Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation), 
**Be Careful: If you plan to [minify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) your code, your service names will get renamed and break your app.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes much difference in the minification process. if you are using `angular.min.js` library then in the production, option `A` fails. in JSFiddle u might use `angular.js` lib. That's why both scenarios work.

Check [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification) for more information about minification

Answer (score -1):

Both will work, but you should follow the second example, which uses the Array syntax so you can minify your code without worrying about the minifier renaming function parameters

Answer (score -2):

try below example

```
var myApp = angular.module("app", []);
myApp.controller("controllerA", function ($scope) {

});
myApp.controller("controllerB", function ($scope) {

});
```